# handling concurrent jobs in a sequential manner

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am working on a bash script where multiple instances of it may be running at the same time. I am trying to prevent this from happening. So I am using flock mechanism to make sure only 1 instance of the script is running. The other instances wait for their turn.

```
exec 200<$LOCK
flock -x 200
echo "secured flock $1"
sleep 10
echo "exit $1"
```

However with this approach there is no guarantee on the order of execution.
For example:

```
# ~/proj/scripts $ sudo ./parallel.sh 2 &  
[2] 10668                                
# ~/proj/scripts $ sudo ./parallel.sh 3 &  
[3] 10674                                
# ~/proj/scripts $ sudo ./parallel.sh 4 &  
[4] 10681                               
# ~/proj/scripts $ sudo ./parallel.sh 5 &  
[5] 10687                    
# ~/proj/scripts $ sudo ./parallel.sh 6 &  
[6] 10696 

secured flock 3  exit 3 
secured flock 6  exit 6 
secured flock 4  exit 4 
secured flock 2  exit 2 
secured flock 5  exit 5
```

I am trying to see if its possible to accomplish the same concurency protection with guaranteeing the order of invocation

The above example is just a oversimplification.

These processes will usually be started periodically say every 5 seconds. But may occasionally take more than 5 seconds(say 10 secs) to finish execution. So I can definitely say that process 2 will start before process 3. But if process 2 takes a long time to complete then there is no guarantee that process 4-6 will start in the same order even though they start about 5 seconds apart

Comment: If you want sequential execution, why are you running them concurrently in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure a solution is possible. Suppose process 3 starts running before process 2. How does it know that you're going to start process 2, so it shouldn't grab the lock as soon as it can?

Comment: It seems like you need a lock mechanism in which the lock is granted in the order that they're requested.

Comment: I'm not sure any of the Unix locking primitives work like that. If the GNU Parallel solution suggested in an answer doesn't work, you'll need to develop your own process manager that implements a queue.

Comment: Sorry, my proposed solution is incorrect - I have removed it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

How about having a queue daemon that you can submit to in parallel and which will then execute the jobs in serial?

From https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-GNU-Parallel-as-queue-system-batch-manager

```
true >jobqueue; tail -n+0 -f jobqueue | parallel -j1
```

Then you can every 5 seconds submit a job like:

```
echo my_command my_arg >> jobqueue
```